# zod-formik-adapter cannot seterrors on Formilk

Tags: reactjs, formik, zod, formik-material-ui

I would like to combine to use zod and formik by using zod-formik-adapter
When I do this:

```
const searchForm = useFormik<ChartSearch>({
    initialValues: {...},
    onSubmit: (value, action) => {
      action.setSubmitting(true);
    },
    validationSchema: toFormikValidationSchema(chartSearchSchema),
  });

  const customGetDetailClick = (e: any) => {
    try {
      chartSearchSchema.parse(searchForm.values);
      // do something
    } catch (error: any) {
      searchForm.setErrors(error);
    }
  };
```

where the I will render like this

```
<div className="d-flex align-items-center error-container">
                      {searchForm.touched.fieldError && Boolean(searchForm.errors.fieldError) && (
                        <span className="text-danger small">{searchForm.errors.fieldError}</span>
                      )}
                    </div>
```

I try to debug error value, and it will come this

```
[
  {
    "code": "custom",
    "path": [
      "fieldError"
    ],
    "message": "Something wrong value defined"
  }
]
```

But it can't to do on seterrors. can I know how to do it
as I don't want to use searchForm.handleSubmit(); for this case